# Choosing government bonds of similar maturity to hold to maturity, shall I just go for the highest YTM one

Tags: bonds, government-bonds

I wanted to buy some government bonds of roughly 3yrs to maturity and planned to hold it to maturity. My bank's app showed 3 bonds of that maturity but one is 0.1 percentage points higher in YTM.

Is there any hidden reason that a bank would offer a bond at a seemingly cheaper price compared with other ones of similar property? If I plan to hold to maturity, is it a no-brainer to take the one with highest YTM?

Comment: There are different government bonds because there are different governments. Are they exactly the same? A state bond vs a City bond? Are they for the same purpose?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep, all are issued by the central government, with different issue dates and coupon rates though.